# Strange error occured in shiro doGetAuthorizationInfo method

Tags: spring, authorization, shiro

I am encountered with a strange error for a few days,and still in puzzled,details are below:

I'm using **apache shiro** with spring,

after some work,I got ready to setup "**doGetAuthorizationInfo**" method,because I'm using "@RequiresRoles" in my controller,

I found if I invoke XXXService(or any service) more than once,the exception occur(first time invoke XXXService,everything work fine),so,I'm try to test "**doGetAuthenticationInfo**" in same Realm which used for login,I invoked XXXService or other services several times in the method,it works fine,

and I also tried to change different datasource component,

so I think it's not datasource component bug,

I didn't find the reason.

When I was using dbcp datasource,exception like below:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

No others are causing exception.

Any other place didn't found this problem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the efforts more than one day,I find something,
I was using dataSourceProxy:

```
<bean id="dataSourceProxy"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceProxy" />
...
</bean>
```

When I change to ref original datasource bean for entityManagerFactory:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    ...
</bean>
```

The error disappear.